# Взятие позиции у QSlider при использовании мыши, клавиш

Tags: c++, qt, slider

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть приложение в котором при изменении положения ползунка QSLider извне (клавиатура, мышь) должен вызываться слот для перемотки трека. Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на линию слайдера ползунок перемещается, но сигнал не реагирует, зато когда нажимаю чисто на ползунок, то сигнал срабатывает.

```
    connect(sldPlaybackProgress, &QSlider::sliderMoved, mediaplayer, &MediaplayerCfg::slot_setPosition ); // Работает
//    connect(sldPlaybackProgress, &QSlider::sliderReleased, this, &MainWindow::slot_onSliderClicked);  // Не работает
    connect(this, &MainWindow::onSliderClicked /* сигнал исходит из  slot_onSliderClicked()*/, mediaplayer, &MediaplayerCfg::slot_setPosition );
    connect(sldPlaybackProgress, &QSlider::sliderReleased, this, &MainWindow::slot_onSliderClicked );   // Не работает
```

Пробовал использовать сигнал `sliderPressed()`, но результат такой же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цитата из документации по QSlider (Qt 5.10)

Signal `valueChanged()` -   Emitted when the slider's value has changed. The tracking() determines whether this signal is emitted during user interaction.

Попробуйте подписаться на этот сигнал, и почитайте про `tracking()`

**UPD.**
Пример подписки на сигнал `valueChanged()`

Заголовок.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void onValueChanged(int v){
        qDebug() << v;
    }
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Реализация.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->m_slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onValueChanged(int)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Добавьте на форму горизонтальный слайдер, обзовите его `m_slider`, запустите этот пример и потыкайте не по слайдеру а по линии (у меня сигнал прилетает и при двигании слайдера ползунком, и при кликании мышкой по линии слайдера).

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо перематывать трек лишь при вмешательстве пользователя (т.к. в ходе воспроизведения трека ползунок будет двигаться вправо в зависимости от воспроизведённых секунд). 

_If tracking is enabled (the default), the slider emits the valueChanged() signal while the slider is being dragged. If tracking is disabled, the slider emits the valueChanged() signal only when the user releases the slider._
Проблема заключается в том, что реакция происходит лишь при прокрутке ползунком, т.е. если кликнуть по линии, то ползунок переместится, но не изменит значение

Comment: @RecursiveDaun добавил пример. Подпишитесь всё таки на сигнал `valueChanged()` и удостоверьтесь, что он вам не подходит.